# Pattern match list elements

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to look through a list and when you find the values 4 and 5, do something?

I tried `foo (4:5:xs) = <do something>` but it doesn't compile

Comment: WHat exactly did you try? The fragment you show is neithere a local pattern binding nor a function binding or something else, it's just a failure. That said, a pattern like `(4:5:xs)`should indeed work.

Comment: @Ingo thanks- so long as me know that should work

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to quote the error message? Otherwise, it must be because `<do something>` is no valid haskell expression

Comment: `foo xs = [y | x<-xs, let y= if x==4 then (x+4) else if x==5 then (x+5) else x]`.

Answer (score 5):

You'll also have to describe what should happen when you *don't* find 4 and 5!

Let's suppose that you want to return the string `"Found"` when you have seen 4 and 5, and `"Not found"` otherwise. Then you could use this function:

```
foo :: [Int] -> String
foo (4:5:xs) = "Found"
foo (_:xs) = foo xs
foo [] = "Not found"
```

If you don't want to 'do anything' when you do not see 4 and 5, you'll have to change the return type of function to `Maybe String` (in this example):

```
foo :: [Int] -> Maybe String
foo (4:5:xs) = Just "Found"
foo (_:xs) = foo xs
foo [] = Nothing
```

I would use the second version, so that you don't have to remember what the 'not found' value is.